# winapi - Hooking an app's taskbar tab events

Tags: c++, windows

I'm having trouble hooking event messages sent when a user left/right clicks on the app's tackbar tab. I have tried implementing `OnNcLButtonDown` and the like but no events are ever triggered when I click on the app's tab. Is there a possible COM solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at the `ITaskList` interface?

Comment: Yeah but As I understand it, all you can do is add/remove taskbar items..?

Comment: You can use the jump list interface to customize the menu that appears. But there is no documented mechanism for stealing the click completely.

Comment: thanks! could you provide a link to some reference to the jump list interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undocumented windows message: code 0x0313 that is send when a user right clicks on the app's taskbar button. Dunno whether its stable to hook though.